# Spot instance termination on AWS without outbidding

Tags: amazon-web-services

A few days ago my spot instance was terminated even though spot price was well above max and pricing history. Some forums have mentioned that AWS can terminate instances if there is a lot of demand for the specific AZ that I chose for my instance (us-east-2c).

I launched another one using an AMI created from snapshot of my root device and it was again terminated within a day or so.

Information on latest spot instance termination:

```
type: r4.8xlarge
spot request id: sfr-af8bceb2-444f-4c44-a1f3-e33a9c90af3d)
cited reason: “server.SpotInstanceTermination: Spot instance termination”
AZ: us-east-2c
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Help with what? Spot instances can and will be terminated at any time, for any reason. If you need the server not to be terminated, don't use a spot instance.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't run any workloads that can't deal with interruption on spot pricing, but you can use the [Spot Instance Advisor](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/instance-advisor/) to help with expectations for spot instance usage and as recommended there, use instances with more frequent interruptions as you improve your applications ability to be interrupted.

There is a chance that capacity isn't available at all, even if you bid the on-demand price. Spot instances are spare, unused capacity, but it can be reclaimed at any point in time. This is especially true as you move up in instance size, or use more specialized instance types. For example, it's unlikely you'll get spot capacity for something like P3 instances very often if at all.